# SVG Web Font Vertical Alignment in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts

As many of you will be aware when using windows + Chrome + Google fonts they can appear very distorted and choppy. I have implemented a fix which overrides the font with the SVG version of the font hosted on my site's server. So we have something like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

The style file containing:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Oswald';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('fonts/oswald-regular-webfont.svg#oswaldregular') format('svg');
    }
}
```

This works well for making the font appear smooth and clean like it should. However I have noticed a problem when it comes to the spacing around the font. If I add a background colour and padding to an element using the font, for example:

HTML:

```
<h1>Oswald Font Test</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    background: purple;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Then I find that the font in Chrome is not vertically central but instead closer to the top edge of the box. Whereas all the other browsers using the font-styles from Google are centrally aligned.

**Question:** Can anything be done to correct the alignment of my Google override?

I think the answer may lie in modifying the svg file's attributes, i.e:

```
<font-face units-per-em="2048" ascent="1638" descent="-410" />
```